# How can I convert currency symbol to universal font?

Tags: fonts

I need to convert svg symbol to font symbol, that you can just copy and paste everywhere without installing special font for that (so just svg to ttf converter won't work here). It should work same as $,¢,₿.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: You would only be able to paste (and view it) sites/computers where the font is installed.

Comment: What do you need this for? If it's for web, it's doable but otherwise... I don't know how you think that would work. It won't. Only if let's say it would be used in an application that allows font syncing, then maybe. — If anything.. `svg` or `png` file should work in many more cases. Like many mobile chat applications allow different image formats, but probably not `svg`. Microsoft word supports `svg`. Technically they support fonts too, but not custom fonts that magically appear in the font list without installing.

Comment: Hey guys! Thank you for your answers. I need that symbol to be same as dollar symbol or other currency symbols in my original post - you can copy and paste them anywhere without installing special font for that: $,¢,₿.

Comment: This is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're talking about web since you mention the requirement of not having to install a font. In that case, you need to use a webfont and the [@font-face](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face) declaration.

In order to create a special webfont , you can use [**Icomoon**](https://icomoon.io/app/). While the UI is pretty bad and confusing, don't be scared because using it is really easy: Just upload the SVG files you have, then **Generate Font** (at the bottom of the page) and you'll get a file with the SVG converted to font and a demo page where you can see how to use it

Comment: I wrote an answer about the process of creating a custom font in Iconmoon [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/109494/how-to-hide-half-of-a-character-in-indesign/109499#109499). Though in that answer it's for local use in Indesign, in which case the font needs to be "installed".

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but just converting symbol to a special font won't help me here.

Comment: Then you must provide more details of what you want to do and how. Like: local environment or web? If it's local, what software? If you just want to copy and paste, why not an image? Is this for different users and computers? Why do not you want to install a source, what are the limitations for not doing it? At this time, all I get is that you want to use symbols and not install a font, so some additional information would help us provide you with an answer.

Comment: @devin I'm working on new currency symbol, so I want my users be able to copy and paste it in text, so they could type something like "$10", "45 ¢", "100 ₿", etc. As you can see, image won't work here. Also I wouldn't be able to ask all my user to install and use font just for that purposes.