# A narrow font with coding ligatures?

Tags: fonts, font-recommendation, ligatures

I am looking for a font that provides coding ligatures, especially arrows, but which has a rather narrow appearance. Hence, could be a proportional font rather than a monospaced font.

1. Font should be free to use for private purposes
2. Coding ligatures should be similiar to [Fira Code](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode)
3. Sans serifs is preferred

Any ideas?

Comment: YOu could take a existing free font and add them.

Comment: There's a narrow font [here called M+1M](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/M-1m). I have no idea if it has font ligatures. The licence in the readme says you can use it for anything.

Comment: @BillyKerr No ligatures with this font at all

Comment: @joojaa Forgot to mention that I am not a font designer at all ...

Comment: @Bunjip nearly nobody is. But here you are not designing a font just a few characters. You can easily do it since this is a special case that has no convolutions at all. No special considerations to make. I dont think you have any other options. This is kindof a unique feature of Fira Code

Comment: Wild, a programming font with ligatures. Why would you want such a thing?

Comment: @ZachSaucier, Fira Code's readme explains it pretty well. Makings symbols out of common ascii character combinations. Not that I get it myself. If I started coding now, I might be into it, but it would be hard to get used to it now. Narrow version though, now that's weird.

Comment: @ZachSaucier Good question ;) . Well, Joonas is right with his suggestion. However in my case, the reason has nothing to do with coding at all. I am writing my speaking notes for, say, a podcast episode, in a keyword style that involves connection arrows from one keyword to another - but horizontally only. Therefore, drawing "arrows" with the help of ASCII characters comes very handy.

Comment: In that case, you don't necessarily have to use a coding font. The point about these fonts seems to be making them look more appealing without losing the meaning behind the characters, hence using ligatures. And while ligatures are a pretty nifty way to achieve this, it's not necessary in your case, because you don't need the arrow to actually consist of `=` and `>` etc. You can type unicode arrows fairly easily too. Here's a post about that https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/369800/126929 - Even though it is about how to do it in Mac, the general idea is the same on Windows.

Comment: In my comment there I mention that I use a [text expander app to conjure these arrows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdrKF.gif). Text expanders are not the only way to do that but I like doing it this way. Even though text expander applications quite often allow you to limit these commands to specific apps, I haven't restricted my arrow expansions to any specific app so I've made the commands a little longer so I don't place arrows by accident. However, if you're confident that you will never need to write like `=>` or `->` in this note taking application of yours,

Comment: you could make a text expander application transform these character combinations into those [unicode arrows](https://unicode-table.com/en/sets/arrow-symbols/) with just as much effort as using ligatures, except you're technically not tied to specific font.  Here's an example of that: https://i.stack.imgur.com/289KI.gif For this example I specifically told my text expander application to replace the characters only after I press space so you can see both of the characters before they get replaced.

Comment: Aaaaaand I don't think this next solution fits your scenario, but sometimes simply making you own symbol font may be the way to go (It's super simple): https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/109499/2332 - So this is basically the same idea as what joojaa was saying, except you're making a completely separate font that you will have to somehow switch to in order to use the symbols. Text expanders also usually allow replacing with rich text, so you can simplify the workflow by expanding to different characters + different font... If the target application supports multiple fonts.

Comment: @Joonas thanks a lot for your comprehensive support. Much appreciated. I get the idea of typing Unicode signs into my text editor or using text expander apps to achive this. However, this doesn't actually seem to save any typing steps. I would most likely need to type a few more keys instead of just `==>` for example.
Plus, I'm on Ubuntu Linux.Not sure if the text expander app would work here at all.

Comment: Finally, creating my own symbol font seems not a valid solution for me, too. Reason is, everytime I need an arrow, I'd need to switch fonts in my text editor ... And I need a lot of arrows in that kind of not taking documents ;-)

Comment: The point about using unicode symbols vs a font with coding ligatures is that they can technically be used with any font. Using unicode symbols with a text expander app is likely not going to make typing any faster or simpler, but it's definitely on the same level, like I showed in the second gif I posted. I think you may have missed that. I'm sure there are text expander apps for Linux too. The main point about the custom symbol font is way more customized symbols. It would be the least ideal solution for sure in your case in terms of how easy it would be to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Narrow font with coding ligatures" sounds like the design brief for [Iosevka](https://typeof.net/Iosevka/).

Comment: Excellent suggestion, but the page you link to shows me an error only. The official page is [on Github](https://github.com/be5invis/Iosevka).

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add this to the list:
https://www.jetbrains.com/lp/mono/