# Weight symbol font

Tags: fonts, typesetting, symbols

Is there an Unicode symbol or common font (present on Windows by default) character that represents a weight?

[image]

These are not what I'm looking for: ⚖️

**EDIT**

I need to integrate this to a Winforms application.
Svg is possible with an additional lib but is never well rendered.
A font would be a good solution.

SVG and bitmaps are not the expected solution, if there is no applying font you know, just say no...

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Not as far as I know. Does it have to be in a font? Can't you just use a vector graphic? What is this going to be used for, in a publication, printed, on the web? What software are you using?

Comment: If rendering is a problem, then can't you use a raster image?

Comment: @BillyKerr it would work but fonts are faster and vectorial, so resizable

Comment: You could start with a vector graphic, and output in various sizes in a raster format as required. Feels like you are putting too many obstacles in your way.  It's unlikely you will find a font with this glyph TBH, and since SVGs don't render well in the application you are using, raster images would seem to be the sensible fallback.  You may be out of other options sadly.

Comment: You could use the weight abbreviation, right? *Kg* it's in the symbol you linked and would work in any font file with basic latin glyphs.

Comment: @Rykara it could be "kg" of "g" or "lb"... so a graphic symbol is what I'm looking for

Comment: Are you limited to 1 character exactly? It just seems to me that there an easier way to go if that's not the case.

Comment: @Rykara if you have an easier way, just post an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all the icons in the world are included in fonts.

Font Awesome has a similar looking icon and this font is generally popular for digital work as it includes a lot of icons:

- https://fontawesome.com/icons/weight-hanging?style=regular

Otherwise use a vector SVG, or use the SVG to generate your own font file with icons: there are different ways to build custom icon fonts for websites/apps. I have worked with some developers that collected all the icons used on a website into a font file, but not exactly sure how that's done, I'm not a developer.

- https://thenounproject.com/search/icon/2351510/

Comment: I know not all the icons in the world are included in fonts, I just need one font with this symbol. There are lots of useless symbols in unicode, maybe one font would overwrite one of them. As I mentioned SVG and bitmaps are not a valid solution in this case.

Comment: @sinsedrix, how about a custom font? This answer outlines the steps in IconMoon (It might sound like a big ordeal, but you just basically feed it svg files, map them to characters and download) https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/109499/2332