# Fallback web fonts for unicode circles (●◐○)

Tags: fonts, web-fonts, unicode

To display a rating on a web page, I would like to use unicode circles, for example: ●●●◐○

This uses the following code points from the [geometric shapes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_Shapes) unicode block:

● U+25CF (BLACK CIRCLE)

◐ U+25D0 (CIRCLE WITH LEFT HALF BLACK)

○ U+25CB (WHITE CIRCLE)

However, the result obviously depends on the available fonts.

Some fonts do not support all code points, some have non-uniform sizes and/or positions for the symbols, and some fonts show the "CIRCLE WITH LEFT HALF BLACK" without a border. See e.g. [preview on google fonts](https://fonts.google.com/?preview.text=%E2%97%8F%E2%97%90%E2%97%8B&preview.text_type=custom&subset=latin-ext).

My question is this:

Is there a single font that is available *by default* on *Windows*, *iOS*, *Android*, and common *Linux* distributions, that meets the following requirements?

- supports these three code points (●◐○)
- circles have uniform size
- half circle has a border

If not, what would be the proper fallback fonts to use for each of these platforms?

Note: I can also do this using e.g. `svg` images, but using unicode characters is much more convenient.

Comment: Have you seen how this post renders on macOS (Safari, Firefox): https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxPKC.png

Comment: @Glorfindel: Thanks for the example. That's exactly what I would like to prevent.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I don't think there are *any* fonts that you can reasonably expect to find on every system. Why not just include your own font defining these three glyphs? Or just use the one below. It only took a few minutes to draw in FontForge.

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: UniCircles;
    src: url(data:application/font-woff2;base64,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) format('woff2');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
body {
    font-family: UniCircles, sans-serif;
}
```

You can try it out here: https://jsfiddle.net/867xnw4d/

This is what it looks like:
[image: 0.5: ◐○○○○ // 2.5: ●●◐○○ // 4.5: ●●●●◐]

Comment: Alternatively, there's [icomoon.io](https://icomoon.io/app), which simplifies the process a bit. Here's a small / somewhat unnecessary walkthrough: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/109499/2332

Comment: Great answer. Some references: [data uri's (rfc2397)](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2397), [data uri's (mozilla)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs), [css font reference](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-fonts-3/#descdef-src)

Comment: Instead of creating a custom font, you can also select the desired glyphs from a google font that supports them (using `text=●◐○`), then download the corresponding woff2 file, and use that to obtain the base64-encoded data-url with the help of [this snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59116157).

Answer (score 1):

While this does not use unicode characters as per your question, you could also use some CSS like so:

```html
<i class="half-moon"></i> <i class="full-moon"></i> <i class="new-moon"></i>
```

```css
i[class*="moon"] {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    border: .25em solid;
    border-radius: 1em;}

i[class*="moon"]::before {
    display: block;
    content: "";
    height: 1em;
    background: #000;}

i.half-moon::before {width: .5em;}
i.full-moon::before {width: 1em;}
i.new-moon::before  {width: 0;}
```

This might be useful in some cases. Adapt according to your needs.